# How to get items of row of a grid in the object of the binded data source of that grid

Tags: c#, datagrid

i have a class clsLedger. I made a list namely listLedgers and inserted some Objects of clsLedger into it and then finally binded it to datagrid.

```
class clsTrialBalance
    {
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public decimal? ClosingBalanceCr { get; set; }
        public decimal? ClosingBalanceDr { get; set; }
        public decimal? OpeningCr { get; set; }
        public decimal? OpeningDr { get; set; }
        public decimal? CurrentCr { get; set; }
        public decimal? CurrentDr { get; set; }
    }

IList<clsLedger> listLedgers = new List<clsLedger>();
Datagrid1.DataSource = listLedgers;
```

Now i want to do something like this:

```
var ObjectClsLedger = Datagrid1.Rows[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `DataItem` of the Row as below

```
var ObjectClsLedger = Datagrid1.Rows[0].DataItem as clsTrialBalance;
```